# How to install latest version of make in centos6.6 docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I want to have 3.82 or newer version of make in docker container for centos6.6

```
[root@046f4766b93f build]# make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

Can someone let me know how can I install latest make version using yum in my docker container for centos6.6?

```
[root@046f4766b93f build]# yum install make
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
 * extras: centos.mirrors.hoobly.com
 * updates: mirrors.kernel.org
Package 1:make-3.81-23.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: try: `yum update`
and after `yum install make`

Comment: @VladoDemcak, that dint help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the procedure listed on [this page](https://pkgs.org/centos-6/russian-fedora-fixes-updates-x86_64/make-3.82-9.el6.R.x86_64.rpm.html). It uses an RPM made for `CentOS 6` located in the `Russian Fedora Fixes` repository though, so be aware of that.

I tried it like this and it works:

```
# docker run --rm -it centos:6.6 bash
[root@1857c0d2c37b /]# yum -y update
[root@1857c0d2c37b /]# curl http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/fixes/el/releases/6/Everything/i386/os/russianfedora-fixes-release-6-2.R.noarch.rpm > russianfedora-fixes-release-6-2.R.noarch.rpm
[root@1857c0d2c37b /]# rpm -Uvh russianfedora-fixes-release-6-2.R.noarch.rpm
[root@1857c0d2c37b /]# yum install -y make
```

After that, the version of `make` is *3.82*:

```
[root@1857c0d2c37b /]# make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

If you want to have it already in a container, just put the commands into a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM centos:6.6

WORKDIR /root

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all; \
    curl http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/fixes/el/releases/6/Everything/i386/os/russianfedora-fixes-release-6-2.R.noarch.rpm > russianfedora-fixes-release-6-2.R.noarch.rpm && \
    rpm -Uvh russianfedora-fixes-release-6-2.R.noarch.rpm && \
    yum install -y make

CMD bash
```

And then build and run your image.

Looking for the package through [`rpmfind.net`](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=make+3.82&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=) shows `make 3.82` available starting with `CentOS 7`. I tried installing that one as well, but there are too many unmet dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the same.